# Clojure map-longest

Tags: clojure, dictionary

I am trying to write a Clojure utility function called `map-longest` (alternate name suggestion appreciated). This function will have the following "signature":

```
(map-longest fun missing-value-seq c1 & colls)
```

and will behave similarly to `map`, except than it will continue processing the supplied collections until the **longest** is exhausted. For collections shorter than the longest, when it runs out of values, it will take them from the `missing-values-seq`. It should be lazy, but obviously cannot be used with infinite collections.

Example use:

```
(print (apply str
  (map-longest #(str %1 \space %2 \space %3 \newline) (repeatedly "--")
    ["a1" "a2" "a3"] ["b1" "b2"] ["c1" "c2" "c3" "c4"])))
```

It **should** produce the following output:

```
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
a3 -- c3
-- -- c4
```

but I may have the call wrong.

How do I implement this? Does the clojure.core or clojure-contrib library already have something like this? As an alternative to `missing-value-seq`, would it be better to pass in a second function to generate the missing values (e.g.: `#(identity "--")` in my example)?

Use case: I am writing a small text spider solitaire player as an exercise in learning Clojure/functional programming. I need to be able to display the game tableaus (tableaux for purists :-)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
(defn map-longest
  ([fn missing-value-fn c1]
    (map fn c1))
  ([fn missing-value-fn c1 & colls]
    (lazy-seq
      (when (not-every? empty? (conj colls c1))
        (let [firsts (map first (conj colls c1))]
          (cons
            (apply fn (map #(if (nil? %) (missing-value-fn) %) firsts))
            (apply map-longest
              (conj (map rest colls) (rest c1) missing-value-fn fn))))))))
```

Test:

```
user=> (print (apply str 
         (map-longest #(str %1 \space %2 \space %3 \newline) #(identity "--") 
           ["a1" "a2" "a3"] ["b1" "b2"] ["c1" "c2" "c3" "c4"])))
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
a3 -- c3
-- -- c4
nil
```

Note that I have taken the `missing-value-fn` approach rather than the `missing-value-seq` one.

**Update**

Updated the code to take care of the case mentioned by ffriend in the comments.

Test:

```
user=> (print (apply str
          (map-longest #(str %1 \space %2 \space %3 \newline) #(identity "--")
            ["a1" "a2" nil] ["b1" "b2"] ["c1" "c2" nil "c4"])))
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
-- -- --
-- -- c4
nil
```

Please note that this will replace `nil`s in the colls with the value returned by the `missing-value-fn`.

Comment: `(not-every? nil? firsts)` - it will not work for sequences like ['c1 'c2 nil 'c3].

Comment: try these sequences: ['a1 'a2 nil] ['b1 'b2] ['c1 'c2 nil 'c4]. You can fix it by checking `(every? empty? cols)` before calculating `firsts` and replacing calculating `firsts` itself by `(map first-or-val (conj colls c1))` (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

This is not completely function you need, but a bit simplified version, so you could get the point:

```
(defn first-or-val [col missing]
  (if (empty? col)
    missing
    (first col)))

(defn map-longest [f missing-value & cols]
  (loop [cols cols, ret '()]
    (cond (every? empty? cols) (reverse ret)
          :else (recur (map rest cols)
                       (conj ret (apply f (map #(first-or-val % missing-value)
                                               cols)))))))
```

I omitted laziness, and you can add it easily with `delay` and `force`. I also changed `missing-value-seq` to just `missing-value` - I believe this is not the problem for you to replace it with sequence or generator.

Example:

```
(print (apply str 
          (map-longest #(str %1 \space %2 \space %3 \newline) "--"
                       ['a1 'a2 'a3] ['b1 'b2] ['c1 'c2 'c3 'c4])))
```

Result:

```
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
a3 -- c3
-- -- c4
```

Answer (score 0):

An implementation that relies on Clojure's internal laziness is as follows

```
(defn map-longest
  [f missing-value & vs]
  (when (seq vs)
    (take
      (apply max (map count vs))
      (apply map
             (fn[& ivs]
               (apply f ivs))
             (map
               #(concat % (repeat missing-value))
               vs)))))
```

and

```
(map-longest (fn[a b c]
     (vector a b c))
   "--"
   ["a1" "a2" nil]
   ["b1" "b2"]
   ["c1" "c2" nil "c4"])
```

returns

```
(["a1" "b1" "c1"] ["a2" "b2" "c2"] [nil "--" nil] ["--" "--" "c4"])
```

Notice that nil is not the same as missing.