# Using 'map' with different sized collections in clojure

Tags: collections, dictionary, clojure, functional-programming

I'd like to understand the idiomatic way with which to operate over collections of different sizes in clojure. Is there a way I can tell the function 'map' to pad the rest of a collection with some default value?

As an example, suppose I have 3 vectors:

```
(def x [1 2 3 4])
(def y [1 2 3 4 5])
(def z [1 2 3 4 5 6 7])

(map + x y z)    ; yields (3 6 9 12)
```

In this case, how can I pad x and y with zeroes and have this yield:

```
(3 6 9 12 10 6 7)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`map` doesn't do it itself, but you can use a combination of `concat` and `repeat` to obtain the desired result:

```
(def x [1 2 3 4])
(def y [1 2 3 4 5])
(def z [1 2 3 4 5 6 7])

(map +
     (concat x (repeat 0))
     (concat y (repeat 0))
     z) ; => (3 6 9 12 10 6 7)
```

Here's the API documentation for [concat](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/concat), and for [repeat](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/repeat).

And here's a sketch of how you could abstract this away a bit, so you don't need to know which of the collections is longest. (In the snippet above, if you `concat` all the collections to `(repeat 0)` you'll have an infinite sequence).

```
(defn map-longest
  [f default & colls]
  (lazy-seq
   (when (some seq colls)
     (cons
      (apply f (map #(if (seq %) (first %) default) colls))
      (apply map-longest f default (map rest colls))))))

(map-longest +
             0
             [1 2 3 4]
             [1 2 3 4 5]
             [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]) ; => (3 6 9 12 10 6 7)
```

You can see a couple other approaches as answers to [this previous question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460986/clojure-map-longest).

Answer (score 0):

You can merge vector of maps with variable lengths by the following function:

```
(defn merge-maps
  [& args]
  (let [max-count (apply max (map #(count %1) args))
        items (map #(take max-count (concat %1 (repeat nil))) args)]
    (apply map merge items)))
```

This function makes the solution more generalized and can take any length of vector of maps.