# Clojure: How to merge vector of maps on the basis of index?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am trying to merge vector of maps.

I tried doing it using the `reduce` method but unable to retrieve the expected result.

```
(def data '([{:padding-top "30px"} {:padding-top "40px"} {:padding-top "50px"}] [{:margin "40px"}]))

(reduce #(hash-map %1 %2) () data)
```

Input data:

```
(def data '([{:padding-top "30px"} {:padding-top "40px"} {:padding-top "50px"}] [{:margin "40px"}]))

(defn merge-data
  [data]
)
```

Expected Output:

```
(merge-data data)

({:padding-top "30px" :margin "40px"}
  {:padding-top "40px"}
  {:padding-top "50px"})
```

Coming from the JS background, I can easily do it using something like forEach and conditionals to build expected output. But how to do it in functional way?

SOLUTION:

I was able to solve this problem in the following way

```
(defn merge-styles
  [& args]
  (let [max-count (apply max (map #(count %1) args))
        items (map #(take max-count (concat %1 (repeat nil))) args)]
    (apply map merge items)))
```

The code snippet makes it much clearer and leaner.
Thanks a lot for all the answers which helped me get up to this point.

Comment: Please add the code what you have tried to the question and how it failed so we can improve on it.

Comment: My apologies. I have updated the code I was trying to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can just use `map` and `merge` to merge collections of hashmaps, but it will end merging when one of the collections is exhausted.

You can create a function like the following to "extend" the collections to have the same length, then merge as usual:

```clj
(defn merge-all
  "Merges two sequences of maps using merge. Consumes all entries."
  [xs ys]
  (let [n  (max (count xs) (count ys))
        xs (take n (concat xs (repeat nil)))
        ys (take n (concat ys (repeat nil)))]
    (map merge xs ys)))

(def data [[{:padding-top "30px"} {:padding-top "40px"} {:padding-top "50px"}]
           [{:margin "40px"}]])

;; (apply merge-all data)
;; => ({:padding-top "30px", :margin "40px"} {:padding-top "40px"} {:padding-top "50px"})
```

Note that in your example, you used a parenthesis around the `data`, but in Clojure this means you want to call it as if it were a function. In the example above I switched it to a `[` and `]` instead. Also, note that this function depends in the fact that you can actually `count` the collections that you pass to it (in Clojure you can have "*infinite*" collections, such as `(range)`).

Answer (score 0):

`(map into [{:a 1} {:c 3}] (concat [{:b 2}] (repeat nil)))`
yields 
`({:a 1, :b 2} {:c 3})`.

`map` reads from both vectors and applies the respective indexes to `into`, merging the maps for each index. As `map` stops when one of the collections is exhausted, we need to concat `nil` values to the shorter collection.

*Edit*: As always, this has already been answered before: [Using 'map' with different sized collections in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940629/using-map-with-different-sized-collections-in-clojure)

Answer (score 0):

I would break it down into multiple simple steps like so:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(def data [[{:padding-top "30px"} {:padding-top "40px"} {:padding-top "50px"}]
           [{:margin "40px"}]])

; be clear about the 2 sequences we are combining
(def data-1 (first data))
(def data-2 (second data))

(defn do-merge []
  (let [N (max (count data-1) (count data-2))]
    (vec (for [i (range N)]
           (let [map-1 (get data-1 i)
                 map-2 (get data-2 i)] ; returns `nil` if no value present
             (merge map-1 map-2) ; if merge a map & nil, it's a noop
             )))))

(dotest
  (is= (do-merge)
    [{:padding-top "30px", :margin "40px"}
     {:padding-top "40px"}
     {:padding-top "50px"}] ) )
```

You could also pad the shorter sequence with nils, then use `(map merge ...)`, but you would have to make sure you get the lengths just right first which would still involve `count` and `max`....not sure if that is simpler.